# Laravel Polymorphic relationship with interface injection

Tags: php, laravel, interface, polymorphism

Been working with Laravel more recently after going on a binge at laracasts, but I'm running into an issue which I'm not understanding, which is maybe just due to my lack of knowledge of operating in this way. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Very simple application, I've got a polymorphic relationship called "invoiceable" on two models, Project and ServiceContract.

Essentially, I want an invoice to belong to a Project or a Service contract, and I've got that relationship setup and working fine.

Now I've got an interface that's implemented on each model requiring a TaskTotalHours method, which I've defined in each model to essentially return a sum of hours of each Task associated with the parent, (TaskTotalHours for a ServiceContract and TaskTotalHours for a Project)

What I want to do is inject the interface into my Invoice creation method on my invoice controller, which I've done via:

```
public function store(TaskTotalHours $tasktotalhours)
```

What I want to do now is to be able to reference the polymorphic relationship when creating the Invoice. As in, make sure on invoice creation that invoiceable_id and invoiceable_type include the right definition (as in if a Project is passed through with an ID of 1, invoiceable_id is 1 and invoiceable_type is "Project")

How would I reference this when building my Invoice object in the store method?